# Statements before non stopping while loop is not executing

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

Why below function is not printing "Just kidding!".

```
void justCheck() {
    printf("Just kidding!");
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

while this is printing "Justing Kidding!" followed by non stopping "Just Kidding inside loop!".

```
void justCheck() {
    printf("Just kidding!\n");
    while (1) {
        printf("Justing Kidding inside loop!\n");
    }
}
```

can anyone please explain the logic?

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()` in the first version (or add a `\n`).

Comment: `printf` buffers the output stream. Sometimes, particularly when you do weird things like infinite loops, you need to `fflush` it.

Comment: @David Thanks! it works. but how '\n' makes the difference.

Comment: @Vasanth-- `stdout` is line-buffered; adding the `\n` character indicates that the end of a line has been reached. As I understand it, it is somewhat implementation-dependent whether `\n` will definitively cause the buffer to flush. Using `fflush()` will absolutely force the output buffer to flush.

Comment: Thanks david. I get that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example

```
 printf("Just kidding!");
```

The output is buffered and therefore not displayed

In the second example

```
   printf("Just kidding!\n");
```

The `\n` at the end will flush the buffer and therefore the string will be displayed.

In the first example before the while loop insert `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: _If stdout is on an interactive device_ which it presumably was in OP's case then `\n` flushes otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks @Ed and dave